# Saving image - path problem

Tags: c#, image, path, save, relative-path

```
public void SaveJpeg(string path, Image image, int quality)
{
    //ensure the quality is within the correct range
    if ((quality < 0) || (quality > 100))
    {
        //create the error message
        string error = string.Format("Jpeg image quality must be between 0 and 100, with 100 being the highest quality.  A value of {0} was specified.", quality);
        //throw a helpful exception
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(error);
    }

    //create an encoder parameter for the image quality
    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
    //get the jpeg codec
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

    //create a collection of all parameters that we will pass to the encoder
    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    //set the quality parameter for the codec
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
    //save the image using the codec and the parameters
    image.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}
```

This line is actually a problem: `image.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);`

If I set path = `"C:/PathToMyProject/imagename.jpg"` then saving works, but if I use relative path then I get error

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I also tried: `Server.MapPath(path)` but no help.

My question is how to set relative path to upload folder?

Comment: What's the value of 'path' when the error occurs ?

Comment: Is this a file that was already on disk (ie, you are overwriting the previous version if a file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps the specified virtual path to a physical path.

`Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/store"), imageName);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/images/Image1.jpg";
```