# Image.Save to relative path doesn't save where expected

Tags: c#, image, file, path, filepath

The documentation doesn't explain the behavior when passing in a path such as "myFile_temp.jpg" but I would assume that it would save the the application directory because this is a relative path, relative to the application we are currently running.

I think that the problem can be solved by prepending the current application directory to my temp file name using 
`string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);` 
Sure there are lots of ways to do it, but this should work.

My issue is I'd like to know why this is happening rather than just throw a patch on it and ship it back out to the users.

Code is WPF, C# project compiled with .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 and runs on a lot of different machines. Mostly 32-bit XP,while the dev machine is a 64-bit Windows 7.

**Can any one explain this behavior and why it's occuring?**

---

**Edit**

The files will on occasion be saved to the directory the user selected files from to manipulate. They resize them, the program keeps track of the size percent for each of the file paths. When the user is finished they will click done and the program will go through each of the file paths, create a copy, resize the image and then save it with a _temp on the end.

Take note that it doesn't always do it and it when it does it doesn't do it for all the files they touched.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Where is it saving when you give it the relative path of just the filename?

Comment: In a particular example it would save to the directory that they had chosen the original files from. So what ever folder that was. And it doesn't always do it, and when it does it's not always all of the files.

Comment: Using an absolute path is not a patch or bodge. Also, like Dave says, what is happening?  Is the file being written somewhere else or throwing something?

Comment: Occasionally it throws a GDI+ error while saving. My guess is that is was trying to save to a different directory and it didn't have write permissions.

Comment: It seem, after looking with reflector, that `Image.Save` use [`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx). MSDN says: The path parameter may specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, use the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) method.

Comment: Can you use an appropriate absolute path, (eg.  C:\Users\[username]\Pictures), as retrieved by a shell call using a known folderID,  eg 'FOLDERID_Pictures'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891880/saving-image-path-problem

Comment: I like Paolo's words. I'll log current directory and see if that is indeed being changed. If you craft that into an answer it's pretty much what I was looking for but couldn't prove.

Answer (score 0):

It works as s expected. You just didn't expect valid behavior. Lets assume that your app is placed in c:/superapps/myapp.exe. You opened command line and you're in `C:\` which means that this your current working directory.

You can still run your app by ./superapps/myapp but your working directory is still `C:\`. And this will be working directory of your app in this case, not the directory you placed the binaries.

That is why it may not have permission or save data in some unexpected by you location. You should always think that your app could be run just like any other command like dir. It will be working in the place where user is currently standing (his current working dir) not in the place it's binaries are stored in